# Azure unable to create any resources in resource group

Tags: azure, resources

Good afternoon,

I'm unable to create Web API app in my resource group (or any other app), when I try to enter App name I get "Could not validate app name" and options under resource group category never loads (opening browser's console reveals some errors like: "type: MsPortalFx.Errors.FetchDataError" and multiple bad requests for "checknameavailability?api-version=2016-03-01"), I have tried creating app resource using Pay-As-You-Go and Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN subscriptions, I have also tried to create them in multiple regions too and I still get the same error. (Incognito mode, different browsers doesn't work).

Thank you all

Comment: Couple more things to try: ARM template deployment? Cloud shell in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app name should be unique as it will be created as a subdomain to azurewebsites.net. If you are already creating it with a unique name, it is worth trying to clear your browser cache. Also check the Azure status here to see if there are any outages or planned work going on in your area: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/status/.

Comment: Hello,

After trying it again today the problem fixed itself, so I figure it was an outage (one of my colleagues had the same problem).

Thank you for your response.